# I find my wines to be too "juicy"

Tags: flavor, wine, aging

I've been making wine (mostly red) at home for about a year now and find that even though I ferment them dry I still find them to taste too much like fresh fruit.  Any thoughts on getting to that aged almost leathery profile that I prefer?

Comment: I don't make wine (so I can't suggest anything specific), but have you tried a different yeast? In other drinks the yeast variety can have an effect on the final flavour.

Answer (score 3):

I've only made a handful of wines, so am no expert, but you might want to look into regulating the acidity, which has a pronounced affect on flavour, and also adding tannins, since these also contribute to the structure of the wine. (For the "leathery" taste you most likely need more tannins - no coincidence - tannin used to be used to produce leather.)

This article, [Difference between tannins and acidity](http://antiwinesnob.com/wine-articles/whats-the-difference-between-tannins-and-acidity/) describes the roles these compounds play and why they are important in wine.

To get a feel for the flavours and other contributions, pour 4-6 glasses and add different amounts of acid and tannins to each to see the effect.

Comment: you may also want to experiment with adding oak to your red wines, most red wines are aged in oak barrels.

Comment: Also try fermenting at a warmer temperature, if you ferment your wine at cooler temps it will end up more fruity, I'm assuming this has something to do with ester formation and vigorous ferments.

Answer (score 2):

You can age them. I'm guessing that you are drinking them way too young. Well I don't really have to guess since you said 'them' and that you have only been making wine for about a year. A wine without age could be considered too fruity.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly using too much fruit, try reducing the fruit to around 6lb a UK Gallon.